# RN Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, render

I know this question has been asked before but none of the answers helped me. I am getting this error in a file which contains this:

```
          <View style={styles.listHolder}>
            {data && (
              <MyList data={userData} onSendRequest={onSendRequest}></MyList>
            )}
          </View>
```

Here `data` is returned by a grapqhl query (Apollo). The error is somewhere in the MyList component which looks like this:

```
type UserProps = {
  data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult;
  //originatorId: number;
  onSendRequest: (id: number) => void;
};
export const MyList: React.FunctionComponent<UserProps> = ({
  data,
  //originatorId,
  onSendRequest,
}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {data && (
        <FlatList
          data={data.users.nodes}
          horizontal={false}
          scrollEnabled
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <User
              user={item}
              onSendRequest={onSendRequest}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          ListEmptyComponent={NoFriendsContainer}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

In this component, the error falls somewhere on the first line of the return which says  `<View>`

What am I missing out? Note that the brackets before MyList come automatically when I use Prettier for formatting.

Comment: maybe in the `User` component.

Comment: User file doesn't show up in the error list screen. I still added it into the qs @Pain

Comment: But that's where the `<Text>` component is, no? We can't see what's in `user` though, and we have no way of knowing what `userName` is after you've processed it. Unrelated, but I don't understand why all the `concat` instead of `\`${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}\`` And personally I'd move that logic out of the mainline render. If nothing else you can default it to `''` (empty string) and see if that helps, otherwise you'll need to include more info.

Comment: I think the problem in the `{data && (...` try with `{( data !== undefined ) && (...`

Comment: @Pain That seems unlikely since just `data` would be *more* likely to evaluate as falsey than `data !== undefined`.

Comment: yeah I know, just to test things, because there is nothing else in `<View style={styles.listHolder}>
            {data && (
              <MyList data={userData} onSendRequest={onSendRequest}></MyList>
            )}
          </View>` that might cause a problem @DaveNewton

Comment: @Pain Right, because the `<Text>` element is in the child component. If anything the additional `data` check is redundant unless the component is designed to be used elsewhere. But the intent and code of the `data` check is fine as-is.

Comment: @Jnl what about the `NoFriendsContainer` in `ListEmptyComponent={NoFriendsContainer}` does it contain any text not wrapped with `<Text>` ?

Comment: remove the commented code '/* <TouchableOpacity' it should work

Comment: @DaveNewton that's a good suggestion about username. Just wondering, what will happen if the lastName property does not exist or is empty? Will it give an error or will it just display it as an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot find any mistake in the code you posted, but try this solution.

````
type UserProps = {
  data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult;
  //originatorId: number;
  onSendRequest: (id: number) => void;
};
export const MyList: React.FunctionComponent<UserProps> = ({
  data,
  //originatorId,
  onSendRequest,
}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {data?(
        <FlatList
          data={data?.users?.nodes}
          horizontal={false}
          scrollEnabled
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <User
              user={item}
              onSendRequest={onSendRequest}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item?.id?.toString()}
          ListEmptyComponent={NoFriendsContainer}
        />
      ):null}
    </View>
  );
};```
````

Comment: data={data?.users?.nodes} along worked. The ```data?(``` above it wasn't required

Comment: Could you explain what it actually means? data will only be filled if the users exist?

Comment: It is called optional chaining operator, it is introduced in 2020 you can read more about it in this article: https://kashanhaider.com/javascript-optional-chaining-operator/